# PS3 Original Theme in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background

I'm infatuated by the PS3 Original Theme, and I'd love to have those waves and sparkles as a background on one of my dashboards. Does anyone know if this has ever been done in javascript? Even if it's just the waves, I'd be interested!

If you're not sure what I'm talking about, here's a photo of it. Imagine this photo, but with the waves moving and the sparkles moving into the foreground (blurred & bigger) and into the background (crisp & small):
http://gameswallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/ps3-wallpaper-aevion-a-graphic-design-blog-w1j2gkbe.jpg

Comment: Is there any reason you want it on js?

Comment: It doesn't really have to be js... I just want it to run in a browser.

Comment: then you should probably use a video instead?

Comment: Pa3k.m you cant changing color when just using video..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are [some examples](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/09/23/animated-background-headers/) of how to create animated backgrounds on a page. You can download the source code and use it as inspiration to create your very own PS3 Original Theme background!